# How to get Camera view like Top-view?

Tags: workflow, camera, properties

I have been trying to make my own logo. The problem I have been facing is finding out how to make the camera face the top ortho view like shown here:

[image]

I want it to be facing right on *Top Ortho* view and want the X, Y, and Z angle to be flawless in order to make the logo stand straight.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Select the camera, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (Reset camera position and rotation), then press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (move up along Z axis) until you reach the desired height. You can consider to set the camera to Orthographic (in the properties window, with the camera selected, the little camera icon) to have your logo with no prospective distortions; in this case change the "ortographic scale" to set the "distance" of the camera, as moving it will have no influence.

Another method is, in the 3D window, press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties tab, select the camera, modify the values in the transform tab to position the camera exactly where you want.

Comment: Got this answer on reddit.Select the camera and open the properties shelf (N in the 3D view). Set the rotation to 0.

http://imgur.com/1BdukZa

Comment: ty though :), have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple just select top perspective move your camera to center of the view which should be changing value of position on z-axis. Now all you have to play with `x-axis Rotation` and `Y-axis  Position`. set `x-axis Rotation` to **90**.. and `Y-axis` according to your need to maintain distance form the view.